How to make :not(hover) not trigger on page load
I'm wondering if there is anyway to make :not(:hover) not trigger on the moment the page is loaded or after a refresh.
I want the button to not be red when the page is loaded, and only be red after the mouse has already hovered over and left at least once.


.test:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.test:not(:hover) {
  background-color: red;
}
<button class="test">hello</button>


codepen

I think you’ll need JavaScript for this as I don’t think CSS has a way of ‘remembering’ a hover.

:not(:hover) is doing exactly what it is describing here - being red when there is no hover on the element. People have strange assumptions sometimes.

understand that css doesnt have variables or able to write anything in the document so there is no way for it to "remember" something. You could do it by using hover on another dom and make sure it stays in the new state, but it comes with its own issues. tldr; use JS for this.

I think you need javascript for that.
You need yellow button on page load and then when mouse enter first time, background color should be red? If yes solution is here


let btnRef = document.querySelector('.test');
btnRef.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    btnRef.classList.add("hovered");
});
.test{
background:yellow;
}

.test.hovered:not(:hover){
background:red;
}
<button class="test">hello</button>




The easiest way i know is to add your test class only after the first hover event.
I would do that with JavaScript.
I would add an event listener that when triggered add the CSS class.
Possibly the event listener would also remove itself from that element so that it don't trigger more then once
Here you can find more on the mousehover event


var element = document.getElementById("abc");

element.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  element.classList.add("test");
});
.test:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.test:not(:hover) {
  background-color: red;
}
<button id="abc" class="">hello</button>




The button needs to be yellow at start
